# send data from custom job to custom php script

Tags: php, scheduled-tasks, sugarcrm

How can I send data from my custom job to custom PHP script in custom module.

For example my custom job do some actions and generate array `$data`

I want send $data to `custom/modules/accounts/mysctipt.php`.

I try use `$GLOBALS`, but in my opinion they are different for job.php and `custom/modules/accounts/mysctipt.php`.
try use '$_SESSION' - dont work.
"/sugarcrm/custom/Extension/modules/Schedulers/Ext/ScheduledTasks/acc_activities.php" code:

```
<?php    
array_push($job_strings, 'acc_activities');

function acc_activities() {
  session_start();
  $_SESSION['test'] = 'all_ok';
  return true;
}
```

"/sugarcrm/custom/modules/Accounts/views/view.list.php" code:

```
require_once('include/MVC/View/views/view.list.php');

class AccountsViewList extends ViewList
{
    public function preDisplay()
    {
        var_dump($_SESSION['test']);
        parent::preDisplay();
        $this->lv->targetList = true;
    }
}
```

Understood what using session in my problem stupid..
How correctly implement what I want without DB. Any simple solution.

Comment: Why don't you get the custom job to simply kick off the other script via an include, or call the other class and pass params via a function or constructor?

Comment: @Fluffeh I dont know how to implement it, in sugar architecture

Comment: @JakeGould sorry, added code